# Cocoapod: ios app and osx test dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I'm having iOS app and i'd like to test some code (interaction with the server which is not iOS-related) in osx test. I'm having 'App' project and 'App' ios target and 'AppTests' macosx targets.

My `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

# ios app
target 'App' do

    ... (some ios dependencies)

    pod 'PocketSocket'
    pod 'ProtocolBuffers'

end

# osx tests
target 'AppTests' do

    pod 'PocketSocket'
    pod 'ProtocolBuffers'

end
```

Is it correct? I can build app for iOS, but i'm getting error for test. `ProtocolBuffers` and `PocketSocket` are targeted to `ios` not for `osx`:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ObjectivecDescriptorRoot", referenced from:
..
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I can see in 'Pods' in Targets `ProtocolBuffers` target Base SDK is `Latest iOS` and same for `PocketSocket` target. `Pods-AppTests` target has dependency on `PocketSocket` and `ProtocolBuffers` targets so it tries to use object files that were compiled for ios for osx tests.

**Update 1:**

I've added `platform` for tests target and cocoapod create separate targets for osx and osx as expected:

```
# tests
target 'ArduinoCodeTests' do
    platform :osx, '10.10'

    pod 'PocketSocket'
    pod 'ProtocolBuffers'

end
```

However i'm still having linker errors:

```
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ObjectivecDescriptorRoot", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's CocoaPod bug.

It creates target `Pods-AppTests` which depends on `Pods-AppTests-ProtocolBuffers` and `Pods-AppTests-PocketSocket` as target dependencies. Then `AppTests` target depends on this target: "Link Binary with Libraries" has `libPods-AppTests.a`.

I had to add `libPods-AppTests-ProtocolBuffers.a` and `libPods-AppTests-PockeSocket.a` manually as their object files path were not added to '-L' when building.